# Rails 3.2.8 Model-Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an assignment page with many assignments. For each assignment I want a link to create a report for that assignment.

On the create report page the assignment infos should be prepopulated, and a form for the report should be rendered.

Any hint how I can start?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a report model lets say the report model has a message attribute, then we can simply do

in your report model should look like

```
belongs_to :assignment
```

then your assignment model should have

```
has_many:reports
```

ensure to include the assignment_id attribute in the report database

Your assignments index action of your controller should look like this

```
def index
  @assignments = Assignment.all
end

<% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
  <%#= basic assignment info %>
  <%= link_to "Report", new_assignment_report_path(assingment) %>
<% end %>
```

in the reports controller we have a new action

```
def new
  @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:assignment_id])
  @report = Report.new(:assignment_id = @assignment.id)
end
```

in the new report view we can simply do

```
<%#= @assignment.attribute basic assignment info %>
```

then for for the report form we can simply do

```
<%= form_for @report do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :assignment_id %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this helps

Dont forget to do this in your route

```
resources :assignments do
  resources :reports
end
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this and let you know how it worked for me.